# Failure in Telemetry Initializers: Could not load "Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-application-insights, telemetry

Application Insight is not displaying the server requests data in Azure Application Insight dashboard. During live streaming I have faced the below error.

> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer fail with FileNotFoundException on loading Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation, Version 1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.

Any idea, how to fix ?

Comment: Check the extensions on the app service using kudu, maybe you have some pending updates.

Comment: Did you make sure you have that package installed via Nuget? That is what fixed it for me.

Comment: installing package in nuget fixed it for me, also look under web.config <system.webServer>
    <modules>
       <remove name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" />
      <add name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" type="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule, Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" preCondition="integratedMode,managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and install it with the nuget package manager and browse `Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation` and installed it

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this issue when adding App Insight in our web application hosted on Azure Cloud Service (Classic). First i did have to manually add the nuget package Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation as it was not added automatically when i configured the Application Insight. This was not enough i had to make the change in the webconfig file and included integrateMode in the preCondition for the TelemetryCorrelation so it looks like this `<add name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" type="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule, Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" preCondition="integratedMode,managedHandler" />`. When we configure Application Insight it automatically adds this module but with only managedHandler as preCondidition which doesn't work for me.